# Css class is not loaded for imageView javafx

Tags: java, css, javafx-2

I have css file:

```
.-fx-attribute-label {
    -fx-min-width: 50;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

...

.img-view {
    -fx-stroke-width: 2.0;
}

.img-view:hover {
    -fx-stroke: #70c0e7;
}

.img-view:selected {
    -fx-stroke: #26A0DA;
}
```

and I try add img-view class to imageView:

```
 pairStream.forEach(id -> {
        final ImageView imgView = new ImageView(id.getValue());
        imgView.getStyleClass().add("img-view");
        facesView.getChildren().add(imgView); //facesView is Hbox which contains imageViews as children
        ...
    });
```

I need highlight on hover and when selected but it doesn't work.
I know that css file is loaded because other class like -fx-attribute-label works. Why it's not working only for img-view class?

Answer (score 2):

ImageView is not a subclass of Shape hence it does not have a eg a stroke attribute - refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html to see what attributes you can set on ImageView.

Your use case has to be solved by wrapping the Image into a StackPane and handling the hover there.

Comment: How can StackPane handle this?

Comment: @Shell_Leko he means wrapping he imageview into a stackpane